# I was using flet to build an apk file by the command "flet build apk -vv ". But it threw the following errors. Can someone help? I am a newbie

Tags: python, android, flet

```
Flutter bootstrap directory: C:\Users\notar\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_BMvPfRFlpx

Creating Flutter bootstrap project...OK

Customizing app icons and splash images...Copying E:\Shehzad\Programming\Rose Elon\MYapp\assets\icon.png to C:\Users\notar\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_BMvPfRFlpx\images

OK

Generating app icons...Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main

File "", line 88, in run_code

File "F:\Scripts\flet.exe_main.py", line 7, in

File "F:\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\cli.py", line 83, in main

args.handler(args)

File "F:\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\commands\build.py", line 518, in handle

icons_result = self.run(

^^^^^^^^^

File "F:\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\commands\build.py", line 731, in run

r = subprocess.run(

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "F:\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run

with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "F:\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in init

self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

File "F:\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child

hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I was expecting it to turn my project into an apk file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is flutter.
I assume you installed correctly but can you give more information about flutter with typing "flutter doctor -v"

Possible solution may be if you don't create an application for windows i suggest to use docker

Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Ubuntu base image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Update the system and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip curl unzip openjdk-18-jre git clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev android-sdk

# Install pip dependencies
RUN pip3 install flet

# Install and set Flutter
WORKDIR /development
RUN curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.16.7-stable.tar.xz && \
    tar xf flutter_linux_3.16.7-stable.tar.xz && \
    rm -rf flutter_linux_3.16.7-stable.tar.xz

# Install and set sdkmanager
WORKDIR /development
RUN curl -o commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip -O https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip?hl=tr && \
    unzip commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip && \
    rm -rf commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip && \
    mkdir latest && \
    mv cmdline-tools/* latest && \
    mv latest/ cmdline-tools/

# Set paths
ENV PATH $PATH:/path/to/nvm/bin:/path/to/rvm/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:/development/flutter/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:/development/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

# Accept licenses and install dependencies via sdkmanager
RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /development/flutter && \
    yes | sdkmanager --sdk_root=/usr/lib/android-sdk/ --install "ndk;26.1.10909125" "cmdline-tools;latest" && \
    yes | sdkmanager --licenses && \
    yes | flutter doctor --android-licenses

# docker build -t flet-ubuntu .
# docker run -it flet-ubuntu
```